# Metabase path for IIS MIME type

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I know how to get list of MIME types of default site.
`IIS://localhost/MIMEMAP`.

I want to know how to get hold off MIME types of different site.

Example: I have `x`,`y`,`z` sites on the IIS server. Now how to get hold of `x` mime types ?
I have tried

```
IIS://localhost/x/MIMEMAP
```

Please help to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [get the mime type](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/working_iis_mime_types) list using

```
adsutil GET W3SVC/1/ROOT/mimemap
```

Where you change the number to indicate the site index

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910658/how-can-i-set-global-mime-types-for-iis6-programmatically)